# Magento payment - Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway

Tags: magento, paypal

I tested paypal on my development environment, when I wanted to create invoice, the system return an error:"Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway."
then I checked the exception log and found:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP CURL connection error #6: Couldn't resolve host 'api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com'' in /data1/sites/testCE/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:983
```

order payment information：

Payer Status:   unverified

Payer Address Status:   Unconfirmed

Merchant Protection Eligibility:    Eligible

Last Correlation ID:    152ec93611d7

Last Transaction ID:    2DT505704J718760U

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you running a firewall on your dev environment? Maybe it is blocking external calls.

Comment: I stoped firewall and then it work fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SSL verification from your magento paypal configuration.

Comment: I have disabled SSL verification from configuration, but still not work.